# Getting image in selected listview Item?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, visual-c#-express-2010

Here is what i am using, but i get an error:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(itm.SubItems[1].Text);
    }
}
```

i get: `InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index`

How do i fix this problem?

this is how i fill the listview with the images in the image list (which are added in the properties items collection)

```
for (int j = 0; j < this.imageList1.Images.Count; j++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.ImageIndex = j;
            this.listView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure that each item does have at least 2 subitems? Maybe you are looking for itm.SubItems[0].Text instead?

Comment: if i do that, then i get another error

Comment: all i have is 2 items in the lisview

Comment: The path is not of a legal form.

Comment: what is the other error?

Comment: Could you please attach the code where you fill the list view?

Comment: I have provided an answer, check it and let me know if this is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You listViewItems have only 1 subitem which appear to be the empty string (which is not a valid path).

An ImageList doesn't keep the path informations of the images. Instead, it created a copy which is embedded in the executable.

Try this code instead:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        int imgIndex = itm.ImageIndex;
        if ( imgIndex >= 0 && imgIndex < this.imageList1.images.Count)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = this.imageList1.images[imgIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'. Parameter name: index'` is the error that you will get if you provide an invalid index into the SubItems collection.  You probably don't have more than 1 sub-item.  Try changing your code to this:

```
private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem itm in listView1.SelectedItems)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(itm.SubItems[0].Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a separate issue.  What is the text of the item?  Apparently it's not a valid path.

Comment: well, it has to be, because they are showing up fine on the listview

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me :D

private void listView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
            var img = item.ImageList.Images[item.ImageIndex];

            pictureBox1.Image = img;

        }
    }
```